# Assign a local variable in callback method

Tags: php, callback, assign

I have a method like this:

```
    $status = null;
    $authority = null;

    SoapWrapper::service('currency', function (Service $service) use ($data, $status, $authority)
    {
        $service->call('PaymentRequest', [$data]);
        $status = $service->call('PaymentRequest', [$data])->Status;
        $authority = $service->call('PaymentRequest', [$data])->Authority;
    });
    return array(['status' => $status, 'authority' => $authority]);
```

What I wanna do is assign `$status` and `$authority` in the callback method.  But phpstorm hints me in the `return array` area that `$status` and `$authority` are never assigned.

How can I assign local variables in the callback method?

Comment: Pass the variables by reference

Comment: With `&`, e.g. `use(&$test)`

Comment: @Rizier123 isn't there any other solution? this seems a bit hacky.

Comment: Why should this be hacky? You want to update a variable in a function which should effect the variable outside of it, so you just pass it as reference